Microsoft Excel Macros and VBA code Web-query Linking for database
Hi am am looking to parse my list of website and create a query connection and a seperate sheet for each, I recorded the macro and created a program that parses the list but it will not continue through the rest of the macro please help
here is my current code i have been using in my VBA:
Sub Macro2()
    ' Macro2 Macro
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+Q

    Dim x As Integer
    Dim Numrows As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim newSheet As Worksheet
    Dim queryName As String
    Dim queryFormula As String

    Set ws = ActiveSheet  ' Work with the active sheet

    ' Get the number of rows starting from A2
    Numrows = ws.Range("A54", ws.Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    ws.Range("A2").Select

    ' Loop through the rows
    For x = 1 To Numrows
        Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell) And IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0))
            ' Check if the value in ActiveCell is already linked
            If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Formula) Then
                ' If already linked, move to the next cell
                GoTo NextCell
            End If
            
            ' Create a unique query name
            queryName = "Query_" & Format(Now, "YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS") & "_" & ActiveCell.Value
            
            ' Create a query formula
            queryFormula = "let" & vbCrLf & _
                "    Source = Web.BrowserContents(""" & ActiveCell.Value & """), " & vbCrLf & _
                "    #""Extracted Table From Html"" = Html.Table(Source, {{" & _
                """Column1"", ""TABLE[id='js-checklist'] > * > TR > :nth-child(1)""}, " & _
                "{""Column2"", ""TABLE[id='js-checklist'] > * > TR > :nth-child(2)""}, " & _
                "{""Column3"", ""TABLE[id='js-checklist'] > * > TR > :nth-child(3)""}, " & _
                "{""Column4"", ""TABLE[id='js-checklist'] > * > TR > :nth-child(4)""}, " & _
                "{""Column5"", ""TABLE[id='js-checklist'] > * > TR > :nth-child(5)""}, " & _
                "{""Column6"", ""TABLE[id='js-checklist'] > * > TR > :nth-child(6)""}, " & _
                "{""Column7"", ""TABLE[id='js-checklist'] > * > TR > :nth-child(7)""}, " & _
                "{""Column8"", ""TABLE[id='js-checklist'] > * > TR > :nth-child(8)""}, " & _
                "{""Column9"", ""TABLE[id='js-checklist'] > * > TR > :nth-child(9)""}, " & _
                "{""Column10"", ""TABLE[id='js-checklist'] > * > TR > :nth-child(10)""}, " & _
                "{""Column11"", ""TABLE[id='js-checklist'] > * > TR > :nth-child(11)""}}, " & _
                "[RowSelector=""TABLE[id='js-checklist'] > * > TR""])," & vbCrLf & _
                "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#""Extracted Table From Html"", [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & vbCrLf & _
                "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Promoted Headers"", {{" & _
                """Set"", type text}, {""?"", type text}, {""Name ?"", type text}, {""Cost"", type text}, " & _
                "{""Type"", type text}, {""R"", type text}, {""La"", type text}, {""Artist"", type text}, " & _
                "{""USD"", Currency.Type}, {""EUR"", type text}, {""TIX"", type number}})" & vbCrLf & _
                "in" & vbCrLf & _
                "    #""Changed Type"""

            ' Create the query
            On Error Resume Next ' Prevent error if query already exists
            ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:=queryName, Formula:=queryFormula
            On Error GoTo 0 ' Resume normal error handling

            ' Add a new sheet and create a list object
            Set newSheet = Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveSheet)
            With newSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
                "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""" & queryName & """;Extended Properties=""""" _
                , Destination:=newSheet.Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
                .CommandType = xlCmdSql
                .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [" & queryName & "]")
                .RowNumbers = False
                .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
                .PreserveFormatting = True
                .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
                .BackgroundQuery = False  ' Make sure to wait for the refresh
                .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
                .SavePassword = False
                .SaveData = True
                .AdjustColumnWidth = True
                .RefreshPeriod = 0
                .PreserveColumnInfo = True
                .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_1_" & ActiveCell.Value
                .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
            End With

            ' Hide unnecessary columns
            For i = -1 To 2
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Next i

            ' Update cell values
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "CAD"
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Quantity"

            ' Set data validation on a column
            With ActiveCell.Columns("A:A").Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                    xlBetween, Formula1:="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
            End With

NextCell:
            ' Move to the next cell
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Loop
    Next x
End Sub


Which part of the code is not executed?

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

What are you expecting from the Numrows = ws.Range("A54", ws.Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count line?  This counts how many rows between A54 and the end of the data - e.g. if data goes from A2:A60 it will return 7.    If the data goes from A2:A48 it will also return 7.  Maybe you meant to use NumRows = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - if the data ends on row 48, this returns 48.

Also the obligatory link:  How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA

Also the code assumes the correct cell & sheet is active when you start running the macro - if the wrong cell is active you're pretty much assured to get the wrong results.

So the code currently parses my data correcty however the error is that it will not cintinue the rest of the macro( clinking the web address in the data it parsed to a new query and creating the sheet for it as the second part of the code has)
